# Strange behavor of wp_nav_menu by not appearing

Tags: menus

It is in header.php

```
  wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'top-nav','container_class' => '',  'fallback_cb' => ''));
```

in functions.php

```
function register_custom_menus(){
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'sidebar-menu' => __( 'Sidebar Menu' ),
            'about-menu' => __( 'About Menu' ),
            'toe-menu' => __('To Exhibit'),
            'tov-menu' => __('To Visit'),
            'media-menu' => __('Media'),
            'top-nav' => __('Top Nav')
        ));
}
```

I do same thing for other theme and the menu appears just fine. I notice that wp_list_page() works as well. But I wanted to use wp_nav_menu so that I could add in custom link using menu admin.

Could anyone tell me why it is not appearing at all?

Comment: Obviously no menu was assigned to this location. Try `$locations = get_nav_menu_locations(); print '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars( print_r( $locations, TRUE ) ) . '</pre>';`.

Comment: **Close vote** as too localized, as no progress has been made.